# combine these statements with self join

Tags: mysql

I'm given the target_service ID and parse param and I need to find other data with the folloowing sql statements

```
SELECT 
    Distinct TARGET_ID 
FROM 
    KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS
WHERE 
    TARGET_SERVICE_ID=3780000000000220;
```

Now I have the Target ID = 3780000000000248

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS COUNT 
FROM
    KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS 
WHERE 
    TARGET_ID=3780000000000248
AND 
    PARSE_PARAM='bkey=5366349'
```

Can I write this all as one sql statement rather than doing two. My experience with nested selects is they are too costly on how long it will take. so if you have a solution with a join it would be better.

The results should look like

```
TARGET_ID,       COUNT
3780000000000248, 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't even need a join. You can just merge the two conditions (on `TARGET_SERVICE_ID` and on `PARSE_PARAM`) and select the count for each `TARGET_ID`

```
select  TARGET_ID, count(*)
from    KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS
where   TARGET_SERVICE_ID=3780000000000220 and
        PARSE_PARAM = 'bkey=5366349'
group by TARGET_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need two queries for this? If the first SELECT returns you the TARGET_ID and since both TARGET_SERVICE_ID and TARGET_ID are in the same table (KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS) you could do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS COUNT 
FROM
    KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS 
WHERE 
    TARGET_SERVICE_ID=3780000000000220
AND 
    PARSE_PARAM='bkey=5366349'
```